# How to error handle on dispatch failure?

Tags: php, laravel, queue, amazon-sqs

I'm using Laravel , queues, and SQS as queue driver.

This is the part of interested code:

```
try{
    $teReq       = new MyRequestPayload($jsonData);
    $jobInstance = new ProcessQueuedSendRequestJob($payload);
    dispatch($jobInstance);
}catch(Exception $e){
    Log::info("==================================================");
    Log::error($e->getMessage());
}
```

Errors may rise from line :

```
  dispatch($jobInstance);
```

As happens in my case if the application can't connect to SQS for some reason.

And I get the following error on logs, and it is not caught by catch

```
Error executing "SendMessage" on "https://sqs.****.amazonaws.com/*****/app-dev"; 
AWS HTTP error: Client error: `POST https://sqs.****.amazonaws.com/*****/app-dev` 
resulted in a `403 Forbidden` response: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<ErrorResponse xmlns="http://queue.amazonaws.com/doc/2012-11-05/"><Error><Type>Sender</Type><Code>S (truncated...)  
SignatureDoesNotMatch (client): Signature expired: 20170906T161652Z is now earlier than 20170907T063633Z (20170907T065133Z - 15 min.)
```

And ... it's not about solving this problem/error itself, but about catching any possible error after dispatching a job. In order to send alerts to tell that my queue application cannot save messages.

I guess this is not caught because the underlying aws-php-sdk is not throwing exception  but just logging an error afterwhile.

Comment: Any luck on this question @koalaok